# How to link a file from Teams Folder without changing/ updating file url in website?

Tags: excel, file, microsoft-teams

I have an excel file in Teams folder. I linked this file using URL in a website.
So, the challenge is every week I upload a new excel file in the teams folder with the same name and archives/ move the previous file to other location. But the newly uploaded file URL gets changed/ updated and gives trouble/error while accessing the file in website. How can I share the file in website when I upload new excel file in teams folder without changing the file link given in website?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are using UI or Graph API to the upload the files?

Comment: No, I upload files in MS Teams and give that link in Website.

Comment: Why are you moving the old files? SharePoint is tracking a version history for you anyway, so the previous items will stay there, and if you just replace the current one the link will remain the same. As an alternative, you can use the "Copy" option on the top menu to move to the archive location, which will also keep the original in place, so when you update it the doc id will remain the same

Comment: @VenkatSai - We are responsible for Microsoft Teams app development related issues. 
For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online). 
For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).